# Spatial diversity: symbol error probability, upper bound

Tags: digital-communications, statistics, diversity

I am trying to understand the calculation upper bound that is given in book.

[image: Introduction to Space-Time Wireless Communications by Arogyaswami Paulraj, p 87-88]

[image: Introduction to Space-Time Wireless Communications by Arogyaswami Paulraj, p 87-88]

**Edit 1: I added 3,44**

[image]

**Can someone explain to me how to come from (5.5) to (5.7) ?**

Comment: Have you seen equation 3.44 as suggested?

Comment: at the very least you could give us eq. 3.44

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added

Comment: @MBaz I added the equastion 3,44

Answer (score 0):

I think eq. 5.6 is unnecessary. To know where eq. 5.7 comes from, you need to realize that 5.7 is actually the average bit error rate. Which means that we find the expected value of eq 5.5 with respect to the effective channel. To do that, let

$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^M|h_i|^2$$

In case that $h_i\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ and i.i.d, $Y$ is a central Chi-square random variable with $2M$ degrees of freedom. The PDF of $Y$ is then given by

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{(M-1)!}y^{M-1}e^{-y}$$

The ABER is then given by

$$\frac{1}{(M-1)!}\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left[-y\left(1+\frac{\rho\,d_{\text{min}}^2}{4M}\right)\right]y^{M-1}\,dy$$

From the table of integrals we have

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-\mu\,x}\,dx = n!\mu^{-n-1}$$

So, the ABER can be evaluated to

$$\frac{1}{(M-1)!}(M-1)!\left[1+\frac{\rho\,d_{\text{min}}^2}{4M}\right]^{-M}$$

At high SNR $\rho>>1$, so, the ABER reduces to

$$\left(\frac{\rho\,d_{\text{min}}^2}{4M}\right)^{-M}$$

which means that the diversity order of this system is $M$. (You can add the scaler $\bar{N_c}$ to these equations, which has no effect on the calculations)

Comment: So how i understood for the last equastion is  E{hh^H} =I ( the identity matrix, size is the nu,ber of the transmit antennas) important: uncorrelated channel. But how does it change in case correlated channel. if E{hh^H} is not equal to the identity matrix?

Comment: This is another question. I answered your question above.

Comment: After I answered your question, you ignored it and asked another question. You don't know what you want.

Comment: i just want to understand the concept of calculation using a different condition. I read a lot of information about it.

Comment: M can have a different value, which depends on DO( diverssity order)

Comment: That's OK to wanting to understand a concept under different conditions. But split your questions to different threads. Don't ask a question, and when being answered, you don't acknowledge the answer and start asking different questions. You asked a specific question, and I think you received an answer.